# Web page's HTTP Header content changes after refresh - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I have a dashboard that is continuously retrieving data from an SAP server. I found a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37934624/7626277) to retrieve the current server date as a way to show when the dashboard was last updated and this date is printed to DOM.

```
//Method from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37934624/7626277

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();

var arr = headers.split('\r\n');
var response = arr.reduce(function(acc, current, i) {
  var parts = current.split(': ');
  acc[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(response); //or initial alert

//Example response 
{
  date: "tue, 12 feb 2019 10:49:10 gmt",
  cache - control: "max-age=604800",
  last - modified: "mon, 11 feb 2019 09:07:33 gmt",
  server: "sap netweaver application server 7.53 / as java 7.50",
  content - encoding: "gzip",
   …
}
```

This works fine in debug mode with every request returning the current response but I get "undefined" printed to DOM in Internet Explorer with debug mode is disabled but contents of the page still updates with the correct data.

My question is:
**Am i missing a configuration in IE OR is this a known issue OR is my request approach wrong?**

[image: After first request]

Comment: Do you get 'undefined' in IE only? Does it work properly in other browsers?

Comment: For IE you have to use `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` instead of `new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: Yes! works perfectly in Chrome but only allowed to use IE with our dashboards. @randomSoul

Comment: @DmitryS. I just tried this and it also only seems to work in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the cookies your server is sending down the date of expiry seems to be yesterday. Is the date time set correctly on your server?

Comment: You might have a point. The second request returns the date as "expires"